# Loop through dynamically named arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a number of arrays with dynamic names (numbered), and I need to get first value out of each of them.

The code looks like this

```
    var array1 = ["1","2","3"];
    var array2 = ["1","2","3"];
    var array3 = ["1","2","3"];

    for (var cols=1; cols <=5; cols++) {
        var imgs = array.cols[0];
    }
```

> I get "(index):131 Uncaught ReferenceError: arrays is not defined" in console

Comment: Put all your arrays into an array and do a nested loop

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Or put the arrays in an object, with the names being the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrays are in the global scope, maybe you can access they using `window` object:

```js
var array1 = ["1","2","3"];
var array2 = ["1","2","3"];
var array3 = ["1","2","3"];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    console.log(window["array" + i][0]);
}
```

Another, more generic, alternative is to save your arrays inside another structure, like a `Map` or an `Array`. I will show how yo can do it with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
let array1 = ["1","2","3"];
let array2 = ["1","2","3"];
let array3 = ["1","2","3"];
let myMap = new Map([["1", array1], ["2", array2], ["3", array3]]);

myMap.forEach(([first, ...rest]) => console.log(first));
```

Comment: This will bound the OP to have array names in sequence and always have number at their end

Comment: @Taplar I have added another alternative instead of delete the answer, maybe the first one will be useful in some particular cases too.

Answer (score 4):

I understood that you want to get `"1","1","1"` first value of each array.

- You can create a array to store all array 3 arrays
- Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the array of arrrays
- Inside `map()` return the first element of the array.

```js
var array1 = ["1","2","3"];
var array2 = ["1","2","3"];
var array3 = ["1","2","3"];

let arrays = [array1,array2,array3];

let res = arrays.map(([a]) => a);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'll be looping through a few more things in the same loop, though. My bad. Should've mentioned.